# Text Editor API. Scintilla for experimental IDE. Do you use something else?

Tags: c++, notepad++, scintilla, text-editor

I have discovered Scintilla/Notepad++ API this week end.
As there is a nice Template vcproj for Notepad++ Plugins [available on line](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/plugin-howto) then I could start to play with some pseudo code-source really really fastly.

I have just looked briefly at the [Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) which expose the API which looks promising. Sometimes it is still hazy for me, sometimes not as feature-full as I expect/dream, but that's really meaningless details for now.

So now it is time I experiment with a language of my fancy, for the moment I nickname it "Entity". And what best to do than design a light IDE for it.

So I am going to invest much time in Notepad++/Scintilla environement.

I have have not thought about using Emacs because I never got accustomed to it.

But if you use another type of Text Editor API than Scintilla, preferably in C++ since it is my language experience... what other Text Editor API would you use/have you used ?

Just want to be sure of my choice before diving deeper.

Comment: Re-read my old post today. The fact is that I migrated all my personnal development into **Vim**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Scintilla to be very feature-packed, and covered everything I needed.  You have to do a bit of work to get all the functionality out of it (ensuring that keyboard short-cuts perform the desired effect, etceteras), but it was incredibly easy to compile, include and get working, though as I said you have to do a bit of legwork to get everything out of it, but this is better than having to tear your hair out getting an "all-purpose" control to stop doing something you don't want to.  It is as if the authors have given you a toolbox to work with.

Comment: Yes this is the feeling I got at first... Wonderful ! I wont have to do the tons of work corresponding to a descent code/text editor... Have you hesitated with others ?

Comment: When I was looking, I had a brief look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/coloredit.aspx but this is a bit old, and as the author admits it is quick and dirty (and tied to MFC which whilst that wasn't an issue for me, may be an issue for you).  The problem with syntax-highlighting text editor API is that they're pretty thin on the ground compared to other, more ubiquitous APIs. Heck, even Notepad++ uses Scintilla.  The first thing I did with Scintilla was put it in a wrapper class and gradually added methods to wrap up the API.  This made it very easy to re-use and customize.